# Incremental PCA in R

Tags: r, pca, online-algorithms

I am looking for a R package that implements Incremental PCA (online version of PCA)

Is there anybody that knows a piece of code that implements such algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a solution to a related problem a while [back](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/fast-computation-estimation-of-a-full-rank-linear-system/20242#20242)

So, in essence, you want an implementation of an online algorithm to carry QR decomposition of a rank $p$ matrix $A$ (or equivalently to do a series of rank one update to the QR decomposition of $A$).

A function to do rank one update to a `QR` decomposition is well implemented in 
[`matlab`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/qrupdate.html), but inexplicably, does not seem to exist in `R`.

Fortunatly, there is an implementation of this function in [`Octave`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Matrix-Factorizations.html#doc-qrupdate) under the name `qrupdate(Q,R,u,v)`. From there, you can call any `Octave` function from within `R` using the [`RcppOctave`](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rcppoctave/) bridging package.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on http://rseek.org leads to the `LPcaML` function from the [`modelcf`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modelcf/) package. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it should get you started.